# Shopify Trekkie loading extra tracking Pixels

Tags: shopify, conversion-tracking, tracking-pixel

This is by far the most frustrating issue I've run into with Shopify. I'm trying to optimize a client's site speed by wrapping up all their tracking codes into Google Tag Manager to reduce the total number of outgoing requests. I removed all hardcoded tracking pixels from theme.liquid and placed them in GTM, went through ALL the apps and sales channels and disconnected from accounts, but there are still extra codes being loaded by Trekkie.

I'm using the Shopify Facebook and Google Analytics integrations as recommended, so those are not represented in GTM. Even so, it's still somehow loading 2 Google Analytics, 2 Google Ads and 2 Facebook pixels.

[image]

As you can see in the source code, there are 2 facebook pixel ids contained within the Trekkie object, but how is this possible when there's only one place to add this information?

[image]

If I remove the facebook pixel id from this screen (Themes > Preferences), then the first pixel will not load, only the second unwanted pixel loads. The same issue persists for Google Analytics and Google Ads, except I cannot see multiple account ids in the source code, I can only see this in the network tab of DevTools and in the Google Tag Assistant.

[image]

I would typically assume that these codes must be in the theme code somewhere or an app or something, except I can actually see with DevTools that the code is being called by Trekkie.

[image]

This is driving me absolutely crazy and I've already spent lots of time trying to make what I thought should be a simple optimization. If anyone can help with this issue I'd be hugely appreciative.

Thanks!

Comment: How did you end up going with this?

Comment: Even I am having the same problem. As per shopify, trekkie is a thing under shopify control. I will try to update here as soon as I find a solution.

Comment: So, I contacted shopify support. I was told that Trekkie is shopify's internal script for tracking the various transactional data. This is used to display the admin analytics in the Shopify dashboard. This script cannot be deleted.